# What is the difference in initializing vector v(n) between the following two cases

Tags: c++, vector

I have following piece of code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input,n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       cin>>input;
       v.push_back(input);
    }   
   for(int i=0; i<v.size();i++){
       cout << v[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << v.size() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input,n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       cin>>input;
       v.push_back(input);
    }

   for(int i=0; i<v.size();i++){
       cout << v[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << v.size() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

for the following input, `n=5, 1 2 3 4 5` , first program gives the output

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
10
```

and the second program gives the result

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

I donot understand why vector is initializing 0's in the first doubling the size but not in the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, *neither* of those are correct for what you want (I'm *assuming* here you want the five elements you input and nothing more - that *may* be an invalid assumption but it seems like a good bet to me).

---

In your first one, you have (comments added to explain what's happening):

```
int input,n;       // n has arbitrary value.
cin >> n;          // overwritten with 5.
vector<int> v(n);  // initial vector has five zeros.
```

This means your vector will be created with five (assuming you input that for `n`) default-constructed entries. Then you go and insert five more, which is why you get five zeros followed by your *actual* data.

---

Your second one has:

```
int input,n;       // n has arbitrary value.
vector<int> v(n);  // initial vector of that arbitrary value (probably).
cin >> n;          // overwritten with five but it's too late anyway.
```

This is actually undefined behaviour since you have no idea what `n` will be when you create a vector of that size. In your case, it appears to be zero but that's just a lucky coincidence.

Note the use of the word "probably" above. While it's likely that the vector will be created with some arbitrary number of entries, undefined behaviour means exactly that - you should not rely on it at all. By rights, it could quite easily delete all your files while playing `derisive_laughter.wav` through your sound system :-)

The most *likely* case however will be one of:

- it'll work as you thought, because `n` is zero;
- it'll have some arbitrary number of zeros at the start, similar to your first code snippet;
- it'll cause an out-of-memory exception because `n` is ridiculously large; or
- it'll cause an exception because `n` is negative.

---

In any case, you should generally *either* pre-allocate and just set the already-existing values:

```
vector<int> v(2);
v[0] = 7;
v[1] = 42;
```

or *not* pre-allocate, using `push_back` to expand the vector on demand:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(7);
v.push_back(42);
```

Comment: can one write `for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       cin>>v.at(i);         
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Hope, one can write the 1st case of writing program in the question in the following way to get correct result

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

for the input given as in the question

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   vector<int> v(n);

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       cin>>v.at(i);           
   }
   for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
       cout << v[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << v.size() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```